# Selectively inherit parts of an entity

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have many entities extending from one parent entity.

I want remove one or more column from only one of them, while keeping the inheritance.
I've tried to find a solution by mapping the parent entity as `MappedSuperClass` but it doesn't help.

Example :

```
<?php

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Base
{
    /** @ORMColumn(name="foo", type="string") */
    protected $foo;

    /** @ORMColumn(name="bar", type="string") */
    protected $bar

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Child extends Base
{
    // How take only the Base::$bar column mapping 
    // and not the Base::$foo column mapping
}
```

The entire [Inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides) chapter of the doctrine documentation doesn't give me any alternative.

I need to really remove/exclude the columns from database, serialisation doesn't solve my problem.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't selectively inherit parts of an entity class. It sounds like you need to refactor your Base class or perhaps introduce another abstract class depending on which properties your other classes share among each other.

i.e.

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
class Base
{
    /** @ORMColumn(name="foo", type="string") */
    private $foo;
}

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
class SomeOtherBase extends Base
{
    /** @ORMColumn(name="bar", type="string") */
    private $bar
}


/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Child extends Base
{
    // How take only the Base::$bar column mapping 
    // and not the Base::$foo column mapping
}
```

Comment: Thank's to your answer, I've used a Trait to keep all my entities extending the parent class. I lightened the parent and added the extra fields in trait, now I just have to use the trait depending on the entity.
Gist https://gist.github.com/chalasr/397c78596c0faa5f0820

Comment: @chalasr that's a neat way to do it

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not allow to remove capabilities of a class through inheritance, it's only made and thought to handle the opposite.

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

You can use traits and refactor inheritance :

```
<?php

trait BaseFooTrait
{
    /** @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="string") */
    protected $foo;

    // ... getter and setter
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Base
{
    /** @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string") */
    protected $bar;

    // ... getter and setter
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FooBase extends Base
{
    use BaseFooTrait;
}
```

=> extending `Base` you have no `foo`.

Comment: I think you have a bit misunderstood my question.
The inheritance is already done, I have many entities extending from the parent. The parent contains mapped properties which are `protected`. So all the child entities automatically inherit the parent's properties.
I want, for one of my child entities, exclude one of the property inherited. Also, I've re-updated the question title to be more precise.

Comment: indeed, I misunderstood !

Comment: Thank you for your job, your answer is exactly what I used.
I will accept the @FuzzyTree answer, because it was the first appropriated answer and the owner has identified my need sort I have all the informations needed to do my logic.
Here the gist of what I've done https://gist.github.com/chalasr/397c78596c0faa5f0820 .
Hopes you get a lot of up-votes, at least you have mine.